# How to properly cite the source of pictures in powerpoint slides

Tags: citations, citation-style, video-conference

I am giving a short presentation at a virtual conference soon, and would like to include some images from the internet in my presentation. Particularly, I'd like to use an image from [this wolfram alpha page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteBipartiteGraph.html). Is it enough to add a text box under the photo that contains the URL of this page? Or should I include a proper MLA citation of the website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is the case with many online sources, they actually tell you how to do so.

[image: Just scroll down a little...]